# Conditional co-occurrence between two matrices R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have two matrices (e.g. distance matrices) and I want to obtain the co-occurrence of row values that meet condition A in matrix A and condition B in matrix B.

```
set.seed(123)
matrix_A = dist(sample(1:100, 4))

   1  2  3
2 50      
3 12 38   
4 57  7 45

matrix_B = dist(sample(seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.001), 4))

     1     2     3
2 0.717            
3 0.332 0.385      
4 0.041 0.676 0.291
```

And now I want to apply a simple rule: how often do...

- a value larger than 40 in matrix A and
- a value larger than 0.5 in matrix B co-occur?

I'd be looking for a single value that is ideally derived from anothjer matrix, e.g.

```
1  2  3
2  1     
3  0 0   
4  0 0 0
```

So here only for the 1st and 2nd observation (Matrix A: 50, Matrix B: 0.717) is the rule true, i.e. the co-occurence value would be 1.

How would I do this in R? I'm looking for an implementation of the conditional comparison of two matrices.

Comment: `replace(matrix_B, TRUE, (matrix_A > 40) * (matrix_B > 0.5))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
matrix((matrix_A > 40) & (matrix_B > 0.5), nrow=3, ncol = 3)
```

Output:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is:

```
`attributes<-`(matrix_A>40 & matrix_B>0.5,attributes(matrix_A))
  1 2 3
2 1    
3 0 0  
4 0 0 0
```